# High Load on Cpu -?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vultr

```
top - 06:49:29 up 16 days,  4:04,  1 user,  load average: 1.29, 1.41, 1.51
Tasks: 113 total,   2 running, 111 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 89.3 us, 10.7 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  1015912 total,    98976 free,   157212 used,   759724 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  2097148 total,  1861284 free,   235864 used.   644952 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
  835 root      20   0  734828  40864   8564 S  5.0  4.0 355:51.95 fortnoxd
20518 root      20   0  748864  41780  12884 S  4.0  4.1  64:35.14 travelpayd
 3147 root      20   0  982540  23532   6712 S  2.3  2.3 295:10.06 node
11230 root      20   0  679384  21044  13552 R  1.7  2.1   0:00.05 nodejs
30422 mongodb   20   0  319176   4184      0 S  0.7  0.4  66:08.82 mongod
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.3  0.0  16:20.24 rcu_sched
  984 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.3  0.0   4:42.43 hwrng
29166 root      20   0   42084   3736   3176 R  0.3  0.4   0:00.23 top
    1 root      20   0   37968   5548   3584 S  0.0  0.5   0:32.93 systemd
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.20 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   3:19.36 ksoftirqd/0
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh
    9 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0
   10 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:04.40 watchdog/0
   11 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs
```

Hello Stackexchange, I have recently been having some issues regarding high cpu usage, I am using a paid service from Vultr, and they are complaining that im using too much CPU power lol, This is my top list, on the vultr website it says im using 105% CPU power on this server, although I only see maybe 12% being used?

Are these 4 processes the only ones consuming power, or are there other things that could cause high usage?

```
835 root      20   0  734828  40864   8564 S  5.0  4.0 355:51.95 fortnoxd
20518 root      20   0  748864  41780  12884 S  4.0  4.1  64:35.14 travelpayd
 3147 root      20   0  982540  23532   6712 S  2.3  2.3 295:10.06 node
11230 root      20   0  679384  21044  13552 R  1.7  2.1   0:00.05 nodejs


root@server-nodes:/# lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                1
On-line CPU(s) list:   0
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 60
Model name:            Virtual CPU 714389bda930
Stepping:              1
CPU MHz:               2399.996
BogoMIPS:              4799.99
Hypervisor vendor:     KVM
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              4096K
L3 cache:              16384K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0
```

Comment: How many CPUs did you rent for this? Presumably 1 if two running tasks and load average of 1.5 means 0% idle CPU. Also, resource consumption can be misleading if they give you more logical CPUs than your physical CPU quota - add  `lscpu` output to your question.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have just ordered 1 cpu on the cheapest package available. I have just added my lscpu output above

Comment: actually its the $5 a month package

Answer (score 1):

The first and most important question: does host's performance meet your requirements. User response time, throughput. If not, change it: make the workload more efficient or add more resource (more CPUs, scale out to more boxes).

You have a 1 CPU box that sometimes reports 1.5 load average. More than one task waiting to run will fully utilize a 1 CPU box, on average. ([Whether fully utilized means stalled is another question.](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-05-09/cpu-utilization-is-wrong.html))

Note from the man page what top is measuring:

> %CPU  --  CPU Usage
>              The  task's share of the elapsed CPU time since the last screen update, expressed as a percentage of total CPU time.

Since the last update interval in top may not catch bursts to 100%. Look at the TIME column for the total CPU consumed over the process's lifetime.

Also try [other Linux performance tools, there are many](http://www.brendangregg.com/linuxperf.html). `perf top` for example will show exactly where in user or kernel code top jobs are.

Comment: Hi... Do you know what the column "Overhead" means, when using "perf top"?

Comment: Overhead is the fraction of samples, in this case on CPU. Called that because using more resources is less efficient - overhead.  I only mention Linux perf because top and ps are relatively infrequent snapshots of the process list, and cannot profile a system in detail.